# Remote Validation using modal ASP MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, bootstrap-modal

I need help with remote validation in ASP MVC using bootstrap modal.

So, I have a modal into a simple form. I have included the jquery scripts.

```
<form id="fModal">
    <div id="modalUpload" class="modal fade uploadModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">x</button>
                    <div class="modal-title align-center"><h3>Carica il tuo file</h3></div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row ">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SocietaId, SelectListHelper.Init(), new { @id = "SetCombo" })

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="file" id="fUpload" name="fUpload">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.fUpload, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SocietaId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" onclick="app.modal.upload()" name="btnUpload" id="btnUpload">
                        Upload
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {     
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#fModal");
       });
</script>
```

This is my controller with action

```
public JsonResult CheckSocieta(SetModel model)
    {           
        object rt = null; //variabile per messaggio personalizzato
        if (model.SocietaId != 0)
        {
            var query = DataContext.CashFlow.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CompanyId == model.SocietaId);
            if (query == null)
                rt = true;
            else
                rt = "Società già inserita";
        }
        else
            rt = "Selezionare una società";

        return Json(rt, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

And this is the Model with Remote DataAnnotation

```
 [Required, AllowHtml]
            [Remote("CheckSocieta", "Set", ErrorMessage = "Selezionare una società")]

            public int SocietaId { get; set; }
```

The action is never called, but the required works.
In fact when I click the button, there is the required field message.

I don't know why the action doesn't work..

Can you help me?

Comment: Seems that this line tripping validation error when submitting: `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.fUpload, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })`, due to `fUpload` assigned as file input instead of uploaded file name. File inputs can't get validated in client-side, it must be validated on POST request by server-side code.

Comment: The problem is for SocietaId too...